# Prolog member + predicate call explained

Tags: prolog, member

I have a hard time understanding member + predicate call. For example when I have a predicate like this:

```
predicate(List) :- member(X, List), someCalculations(X).
```

And let's suppose that the predicate `someCalculations(X)` sometimes returns true and sometimes false, or just false/true. Will it stop for the first true returned or when all the `X` members from List return true ? And when will it fail, when it encounters fail once, or when all the List members failed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicate calls in Prolog don't "return false/true"; they *succeed* (optionally binding variables) or *fail*. And they can succeed repeatedly.

The answer to your question depends on how you call `predicate`. Assuming it's a goal by itself, and you pass it a list containing no unbound variables, e.g. `?- predicate([a,b,c,d])`, this will happen:

1. `member(X,[a,b,c,d])` first succeeds with `X=a`. Then `someCalculations(a)` gets called.

   1. If it succeeds, `predicate([a,b,c,d])` call also succeeds, without binding any variables. You can stop, or you can ask for more results in which case...
   2. If it fails, Prolog backtracks and...
2. ... `X` gets bound to `b`, `someCalculations(b)` is called. Etc.

After step 4 (with `d`), `member` call fails so `predicate` call does as well (`someCalculations` doesn't get called).

Comment: Is this the same when using recursion instead of some other predicate ? :)